# Is it possible to invoke create/new method in Model and forbid controller from invoke create/new methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models and want model B can control model A's CRUD methods and disallow A's CRUD methods to be invoked in other CONTROLLERs.
Is it possible to do that in Rails?

E.g.

I should not be able to invoke A.create, A.new in any controller.
And only be able to invoke  A.create, A.new from model B.

Comment: Why? Whats the actual use? A method in Ruby does not usually know what context it is called in (unless you pass it via parameters or globals) so it sounds like a fools errand.

Comment: Not enough detail in the question, expand upon the requirement please.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Just don't provide routes and interfaces for model A, and implement your custom logic all in model B. You don't even need to create a controller or views for model A if you don't need them.